# Loop and fill values randomly (string) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataset which has columns named "dish_liked" it has values like based on the corresponding columns which is named "rest_type" and it has input like "Cafe" "Quick Bites" "Delivery" etc

Output of "dish_liked" columns when corresponding column "rest_type" values = "Quick Bites"

```
Waffles                                                                                                                  43
Nutella Pancakes                                                                                                         17
Donut, Coffee                                                                                                            14
Apple Pie, Mascarpone Cheese, Nolen Gurer Ice Cream, Paan Ice Cream, Nolen Gur, Gur Ice Cream, Salted Caramel            13
Coffee, Berryblast, Nachos, Chocolate Waffles, Nutella Waffle, Chocolate Overload, Sandwiches                            12
```

Now I've Nan values in the columns "dish_liked" and I want to fill them on the basis of corresponding column "rest_type".

My logic is I'll fetch the top 5 values (string) from "dish_liked" on the basis of "rest_type" and fill randomly.

eg : `new_df.loc[new_df['rest_type'].isin(['Dessert Parlor']) , 'dish_liked'].value_counts()[0:5]`

```
Waffles                                                                                                                  43
Nutella Pancakes                                                                                                         17
Donut, Coffee                                                                                                            14
Apple Pie, Mascarpone Cheese, Nolen Gurer Ice Cream, Paan Ice Cream, Nolen Gur, Gur Ice Cream, Salted Caramel            13
Coffee, Berryblast, Nachos, Chocolate Waffles, Nutella Waffle, Chocolate Overload, Sandwiches                            12
```

Now if the dish liked column has Nan value and it's corresponding column "rest_type" values = "Dessert Parlor" or "Cafe" etc. I want to fill the these upper top 5 values (string) on these Nan Values.

How can I do that ? Sorry if it sound confusing. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to add a comment explaining instead answer your own question with another question. Lets make it simple for everyone. You seem all over the place with your explanation. Above you have insert a few arrays, do you want them to come together for example: ['Burgers','Pasta',...] or one value per time to replace the nan values? If so I have a solution for it, I just need to see what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: I simply want to fill all the Nan values in "dish_liked" columns on the basis of corresponding columns  "rest_type" if this 'rest_type' columns has value == 'Cafe" then corresponding column "dish_liked" column Nan value should be filled with the output of df['rest_type'].value_counts()[0:5] [I want to fill these 5 values randomly in the dish_liked columns] Same with the case of other value in 'rest_type' like 'Chinese' 'Delivery' etc. Hope I'm clear this time. Thanks once again

Comment: you mentioned that you have a delivery column, I don't know the structure of your df, so if you want a better approach you will need to either provide a sample of it, either create a dummy df with the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you still did not understand from my point is:
1 - your top 5 are tuples, not a flat list
2 - If you want to use a tuple the approach has to be different, which I don't be believe to be the case. Below you have two versions to get your job done, the first one is pretty manual and the second one will make it very dynamic and easy for you to get the job as you expect. There are marks all the way in the code to explain the logic as you said that yo are a newbie.

 You are welcome dude.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

#Adding top 5 manually aiming to simplify the logic
top5 = ['Friendly Staff','Burgers', 'Coffee', 'Waffles', 'Mocktails', 'Pasta', 'Brownie' 'Chocolate', 'Chicken Salami',
'Burgers', 'Pasta', 'Chocolate Mousse', 'Potato Wedges', 'Cup Cake', 'Cheesy Fries', 'Peri Peri Chicken',
'Burgers', 'Coffee', 'Cappuccino', 'Barbeque Burger', 'Sandwiches', 'Spinach Pasta', 'Sandwich',
'Bannoffee Pie', 'Pasta', 'Sandwiches', 'Salsa', 'Sandwich', 'Salads', 'Pita Bread']
#eliminating duplicates with set
top5 = list(set(top5))
top5C = ['Nuddles','Rice','Mapo Tofu','Chow Mein','Chinese Hot Pot']
top5D = ['Fast','Slow','Great','Not happy','Extremely happy']

#dummy df
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({'Rest_type':['Cafe','Others','Cafe','Chinese','Delivery','Cafe'],
                       'dish_liked':['Brownie','Waffles', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

#replacing nan values with the list created above, function randomchoice will pick a random values within a list
#basically everytime you call the script it will add different values
dfTest = dfTest.fillna(dfTest.loc[dfTest['Rest_type'] == 'Cafe'].fillna(random.choice(top5)))
dfTest = dfTest.fillna(dfTest.loc[dfTest['Rest_type'] == 'Chinese'].fillna(random.choice(top5C)))
dfTest = dfTest.fillna(dfTest.loc[dfTest['Rest_type'] == 'Delivery'].fillna(random.choice(top5D)))


#now how you make it dynamic and easy the hassle
#fucntion to collect all top 5 by category
def build_di(df, k):
    di = {k: df[df.Rest_type == k]['dish_liked'].value_counts()[:5]}
    return di

#create a list of unique values from the Rest_type column
i = dfTest.Rest_type.unique()

#Use the first value to build the dictionary with the function
di = build_di(dfTest, i[0])

#Add all the other categories with a for loop
for x in i[1:]:
    di.update(build_di(dfTest, x))


#with the dictionary below I tested the last function and it worked like a charm.   
#di = {'Cafe':top5,'Chinese':top5C,'Delivery':top5D}

#here the for loop will iterate each category('cafe','chinese','delivery') in your case
#filter the df then filter which list in the dictonary it will select a random value
for k in di.keys():
    dfTest =  dfTest.fillna(dfTest.loc[dfTest['Rest_type'] == k].fillna(random.choice(di[k])))
dfTest
```

[image: outcome]

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation. When I'm applying it df['dish_liked' = dfTest.fillna(dfTest.loc[dfTest['Rest_type'] == 'Cafe'].fillna(random.choice(top5))) then it's assigning other columns value which is named 'address' to the 'dish_liked' columns. And when I'm directly applying using "new_df.dish_liked.fillna(new_df.loc[new_df['rest_type'] == 'Cafe'].fillna(random.choice(list_cafe)))"  then it's giving an error ""value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame""